# Regex: Delete tags so as to remain only the content beetween them

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I want to delete `<em>` and `<em/>` tags  from some lines.

For example:

> `target="_new"><em>&ldquo;Superman (2007)&quot;</em>`

My desire output:

> `target="_new">&ldquo;Superman (2007)&quot;`

I made a regex, but something it's not working:

Search: `(target="_new">)(?<=<em>)(.*?)(?=/</em>)`

Replace by: `\3`

Comment: `(?s)(target="_new">)<em>(.*?)</em>` > `\1\2`

Comment: Don't regular expressions use a greedy parser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Find Wha**t: `^(target="_new">)<em>(.*?)</em>$`
**Replace With**: `\1\2`

---

**Input**:

```
target="_new"><em>&ldquo;Superman (2007)&quot;</em>
```

**Output**:

```
target="_new">&ldquo;Superman (2007)&quot;
```

---

[image]

Comment: Now try that on a line that has multiple `<em>`/`</em>` pairs.